# Unit testing float operations in Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-3.5, floating-point

I have some C# unit tests that perform some float/double operations and I would like to unit test them.  Assert.AreEqual is insufficient because of rounding errors.

Take unit conversion as an example.  10.5 meters to feet has a conversion factor of 3.281 so I get 34.4505.  Using a more accurate conversion factor gives me 34.4488189.  I want to test this within, say, 0.1 (so 34.3488-34.5488 would pass the test).

I could certain manually test the value with a tolerance in my unit test but that's highly repetitive and the failure message wouldn't be very descriptive (again without having to write my own Assert failure message):

```
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(34.4488189 - value) < 0.1);
```

**How can I unit test my float operations to within a certain error tolerance?**  I cannot find any Assert classes that do this that come with VS.  Am I missing it or do I have to roll my own?

**Are there standard practices in testing floats/doubles to keep in mind?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assert.AreEqual in MSTest has overloads that accept a delta (error tolerance) parameter:

```
public static void AreEqual (double expected, double actual, double delta)
```

for example:

```
Assert.AreEqual(34.4488189, value, 0.1);
```

or, for the smallest possible tolerance:

```
Assert.AreEqual(34.4488189, value, double.Epsilon);
```

Comment: Hah!  18 overloads for AreEqual.  Not much wonder I didn't catch it.

Comment: warning, using `double.Epsilon` will not do what you want it to do. Epsilon is the smallest double precision value. This only applies if you are comparing values that are on the order of 10^-324, which is very unlikely. What you want to do is compare double values up to the last digit that they can represent. Thus the tolerance could be a thousand if you are comparing values that are in the quadrillions. The buzz word is "ULP" (units in last place) . see http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: If you're using XUnit, `Assert.Equal()` for doubles takes a similar-but-different third parameter: `precision` which is an **integer** specifying the number of decimal places to care about.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [NUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit) framework:

```
//Compare Float values
Assert.AreEqual(float expected, float actual, float tolerance);
Assert.AreEqual(float expected, float actual, float tolerance, string message);

//Compare Double values
Assert.AreEqual(double expected, double actual, double tolerance);
Assert.AreEqual(double expected, double actual, double tolerance, string message)
```

(Above taken from [this](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0411051&page=2) article)

More listed [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.2.7).

Answer (score 2):

NUnit can compare within a tolerance by providing a third argument of the AreEqual method. Have a look at [NUnit Equality Asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.5)

Visual Studio Unit Testing also has this: [AreEqual Method (Double, Double, Double, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243456.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone so forgive the lack of code/links.

There's a question on here about favourite c# extensions where people have extended built-in type such as string. You could extend the float type with a method that would work like this:

```
Myfloat.IsInTolerance(34.8f, 0.1f)
```

..which would return true if the Myfloat float was 0.1 either side of 34.8. It could make it less laborious.

Answer (score 0):

Look at NUnit Equality Constraints, they are flexible! Hope it can help!